# Circle/Triangle math problem

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

The question asks to find angles $\angle X$ and $\angle Y$, however I don't know how to do this without assuming that lines $\overline {GO}$ and $\overline{OJ}$ are parallel. The only angle given is $32$ degrees.

[image]

Comment: Looks like $GO$ and $OJ$ are the same line. I'd say it is implied in the picture. If not, then $G$ is absolutely arbitrary and there is no way to find $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\angle H=90^{\circ}$ is over diameter so $\angle x +32^{\circ}+90^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$ so $$\angle x=58^{\circ}$$ as Americo pointed $$\angle y=180^{\circ}-\angle x=132^{\circ}$$

Comment: Typo: $x=58^{\circ}$ instead of $x=48^{\circ}$.

Comment: edited thank you Americo

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the angle subtended by a chord from a point on a circle is $1/2$ that subtended by the chord from the center of the circle.

$$\angle GOH = 2 \angle GJH$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now

Answer (score 1):

Hint: See [Wikipedia entry: Inscribed angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle_theorem#Proof_2) and show that $$\angle x+\angle y=180^{\circ}.$$

Answer (score 0):

∠JHG=90

∠HJG+∠JHG+∠JGH=180

90+32+x=180

X=58